# ASP.NET Core DataTable Layout and feature issue

Tags: .net-core

I am using datatable in which data populate  through Model passed by controller. When we edit data in modal form, data is updated properly and shown in table. But this time table-layout gets changed into normal table. In that case all features of DataTable get lost.

```
@model IEnumerable<IDESK.Models.UserMaster.UserRegn>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div id="modal-placeholder"></div>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Sales_Plan</title>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper" id="mainbody">
        <h4 style="color:indigo">User Master Index</h4>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="UploadFileData">
            <button type="button" id="btnCreatUser" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="ajax-modal" data-bs-target="#User_Master_Modal"
                    data-url="@Url.Action("Create")">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                Create
            </button>
            <input type="submit" id="thisbutton" value="Upload data" class="btn btn-primary" />
            @{
                <!--accept="csv/CSV"-->
                if (TempData["upload"] == "OK")
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Save List", "SaveList", new { action = "SaveList" }, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary small" })
                }
            }
            <div>
                <input type="file" id="fileName" name="fileName" accept="Text/CSV" title="Select a file" style="margin-top:5px" />
            </div>
        </form>
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_TblUserMaster", Model)
    </div>
    @{
        if (TempData["Message"] != null)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Raw(TempData["Alert"])
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</body>
</html>

<link href="~/lib/select2/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/select2/js/select2.js"></script>

@*<script src="~/lib/datatables/js/jquery.datatables.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/datatables/js/datatables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/datatables/js/jquery.datatables.min.js"></script>
*@
@section Scripts
    {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    <script>

        $(function () {

            *$("#tblUserMaster").DataTable({});*
                   
            var placeholderElement = $('#modal-placeholder');
            
            $(document).on('click', 'button[data-bs-toggle="ajax-modal"]', function (event) {
                $("#btnCreatUser").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Loading...');
                document.getElementById("btnCreatUser").disabled = true;

                var url = $(this).data('url');
                $.get(url).done(function (data) {
                    placeholderElement.html(data);
                    placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
                    $('.modal').draggable();
                    TouchPopUp();
                });
            });
            placeholderElement.on('click', '[data-bs-dismiss="modal"]', function (event) {
                $("#btnCreatUser").html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create');
                document.getElementById("btnCreatUser").disabled = false;
            });

            placeholderElement.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $("#btnCreatUser").html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create');
            });
            //alert("site");
            placeholderElement.on('click', '[data-bs-save="modal"]', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
                var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
                var dataToSend = new FormData(form.get(0));

                $.ajax({ url: actionUrl, method: 'post', data: dataToSend, processData: false, contentType: false }).done(function (data) {
                    var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);
                    placeholderElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);

                    var isValid = newBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val() === 'True';
                    if (isValid) {
                        var notificationsPlaceholder = $('#notification');
                        var notificationsUrl = notificationsPlaceholder.data('url');
                        $.get(notificationsUrl).done(function (notifications) {
                            notificationsPlaceholder.html(notifications);
                        });

                        var tableElement = $('#tblUserMaster');
                        var tableUrl = tableElement.data('url');
                        $.get(tableUrl).done(function (table) {
                            tableElement.replaceWith(table);
                        });
                        
                          placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
                        alert("Success : Document Saved !");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Error : Document did not Save !");
                    }
                    $("#btnCreatUser").html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create');
                    document.getElementById("btnCreatUser").disabled = false;
                    //----FG Material Grade
                    $('#ddlDepartment').select2({
                        dropdownParent: $('#User_Master_Modal'),
                        placeholder: "Department",
                        allowClear: true,
                        theme: "classic",
                        dropdownPosition: 'below'
                    });
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
    
}
```

This is my first initializing table screen:

[First Image (okay)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlUB5.png)

And this image after table data updated:

[Second Image (not okay)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz8AZ.png)

I have tried lots article from Stackoverflow and other resources.
I want my DataTable's structure and features like sorting, paging & searchins remains intact.